# Bash test command to check files exists not works as expected

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a simple bash script. I need to check if file exists and then do some actions related to check result. Script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

productionPackageJsonPath=/var/www/portaldev/current/package.jsonxxx
productionNodeModulesPath=/var/www/portaldev/current/node_modules

hasPackageJsonFile=$(test -f productionPackageJsonPath)
hasDiff=""

if [ "$hasPackageJsonFile" == "true"  ]
then
    echo "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    hasDiff=$(diff ${productionPackageJsonPath} package.json)
else
    echo "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
fi
```

This should return false cause package.jsonxxx does not exist. But I am getting always true or i dont know what. But console always write echo "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

Can somebody tell me please what am I doing wrong? Thnxsm.

Comment: where is the `-f`?

Comment: $(test -f productionPackageJsonPath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my solution is:

```
productionPackageJsonPath=/var/www/portaldev/current/package.json

if [ -f $productionPackageJsonPath ]
then
    echo "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    hasDiff=$(diff ${productionPackageJsonPath} package.json)
else
    echo "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
    hasDiff=""
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hasPackageJsonFile=$(test -f productionPackageJsonPath)
```

Now the output of the command `test -f productionPackageJsonPath` is assigned to `hasPackageJsonFile`. This variable will always be empty, since $(...) captures the output of programs, not results.

Comment: Thanks, but how to assign a result to the variable? Obviously I need result in variable.

Comment: `lastresult=$?` stores the error of the last command (0 := no error, success) in a variable, but you might as well (most of the time) use an if around the test directly, instead of an intermediate variable.